# Calculate all items on every sale.order from another class - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I need to calculate all the `amount_total` from every sale order on `draft` state.

I can read all the sales in this domain by doing:

```
sale_order = fields.Many2one('sale.order', domain=[('state', '=', 'draft')], string="Sales Planned")
amount_total = fields.Float("Total Planned Sales", related="sale_order.amount_total")
```

But in this way, I can only search for one sale order at a time, and then the `amount_total` just shows the total from the sale order I've salected.

So, how can read all sales orders on `draft` state and, based on that, calculate all the `amount_total` ?

There is the `_amount_all` function, but I guess it needs to be overwritten somehow.

**EDIT**

This is how my class looks like right now:

```
class account_budget_bsi_line(models.Model):
_name = 'account.budget.bsi.line'
_inherit = ['sale.order', 'stock.location', 'stock.move', 'purchase.order',]

@api.one
def _compute_sales_bsi(self):
    self.sales_bsi = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft')])

account_budget_bsi_id = fields.Many2one('account.budget.bsi', ondelete='cascade', select=True, required=True) 
opening_stock = fields.Float(string="Opening stock")
sale_order = fields.Many2one('sale.order', domain=[('state', '=', 'draft')], string="Sales Planned")
#amount_total = fields.Float("Total Planned Sales", related="sale_order.amount_total")
amount_total = fields.Float("Total Planned Sales", compute="_compute_amount_total")
sales_bsi =  fields.One2many('sale.order', compute="_compute_sales_bsi", string="Sales Test")
#sales_state = fields.Selection(related='sale_order.state', string="Sales Planned")
interauxiliary_transfers = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="Interauxiliary transfers")
interauxiliary_receipts = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="Interauxiliary receipts")
auxiliary_receipts = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="Auxiliary receipts")
prod_purchased = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="Products Purchased")
closing_stock = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="Closing stock")

@api.multi
@api.depends('sale_order')
def _compute_amount_total(self):
    draft_orders = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft')])
    amount_total = sum(draft_orders.mapped('amount_total')
    for record in self:
        record.amount_total = amount_total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the model you are creating these fields on, so I'm guessing a little bit here.

Why don't you just make `amount_total` a [computed field](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields)?

```
amount_total = fields.Float("Total Planned Sales", compute="_compute_amount_total")

@api.multi
@api.depends('fields_depended_on')
def _compute_amount_total(self):
    draft_orders = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft')])
    amount_total = sum(draft_orders.mapped('amount_total'))
    for record in self:
        record.amount_total = amount_total
```

Comment: Hi, looks like a wonderful solution, can be useful for other models too, but for some weird reason every time I try to update the module it says ´    for record in self:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax´

Comment: I don't get it, seems perfect, also checked indentation

Comment: @Kristian Can you update your Question with the code you gave, including the class definition?

Comment: Sure... I'm updating it

Comment: Done, the error is on ´for record in self:´ I also tried ´for record in self.sale_order:´ same error :/

Comment: @KristianYou are missing a parenthesis on the line above there `amount_total = sum(draft_orders.mapped('amount_total')`. Add an extra closing parenthesis and you should be good to go. Seems that's from my answer as well, so I'll update there.